# Fonts difference between website & Invsion (Designers & Front End developers tool)

Tags: css, fonts, frontend, webfonts, web-frontend

I'm struggling making our website font look exactly like the designer meant it to be.

We've used Google 'Source Sans Pro' file.
I've tried several strategies:

- Using directly from google [https://fonts.google.com/?query=source+sans+pro]
- Download **TTF** files from Google and use them using @font-face
- Convert these TTF files to **WOFF/WOFF2** files using font squirrel as Google recommended https://www.gorges.us/blog/google-fonts
- Tried using this font on an empty clean angular CLI 6 project

Unfortunately, none of the above made the font look similar.

Does anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Most fonts do look differently in PhotoShop and the browser. If you want to get it as close as possible, ask the designer to export the font file and then add into into your directory and add via @font-face.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer.
Our designer uses Invision and loads this google font to it.
Are you familiar with Invision? Do you think it behaves like photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

The differences are caused by the software that actually paints the font on the screen: the render engine. A browser or design program can have a custom one, or one based on an [open source one](https://www.freetype.org/), or delegate it to the OS. Subtle differences between how these render engines decide to turn vector shapes into pixels will cause small visual differences.

Your font will never look pixel perfect on every OS and browser, and that's perfectly fine!